# Concatenar CPF no Mysql

Tags: mysql

Boa Tarde

Gostaria de saber como faço para concatenar 11 dígitos no formato de um CPF.
Tipo, formatar para um CNPJ, fiz isto:

```
update ger_ter set cpfcgc = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(cpfcgc, 1,2), '.', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,3,3), '.', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,6,3), '/', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,9,4), '-', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,13, 2))
where length(cpfcgc) =14 and pessoa=1;
```

Só que não estou conseguindo 'pegar' esta mesma ideia e deixar para formatar CPF. Já to batendo pino aqui.
Valeu

Comment: qual a dificuldade/erro? se o cpf tem esse formato "123.456.789-00" só contar a posição de cada grupo e mudar o `substring`

Comment: A dificuldade era só trocar este SQL que informei para poder servir para o CPF também. Mas já o pessoal já me ajudou. Obrigado a você também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue uma solução para aplicar a máscara dependendo da quantidade de caracteres:

Exemplo em um select:

```
SELECT
    cpfcgc,
    IF(
        LENGTH(cpfcgc) = 14,
         CONCAT(SUBSTRING(cpfcgc, 1,2), '.', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,3,3), '.', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,6,3), '/', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,9,4), '-', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,13, 2)),
        CONCAT(SUBSTRING(cpfcgc, 1,3), '.', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,4,3), '.', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,7,3), '-', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,10,2))
    ) AS mascarado
FROM
    (SELECT '12345678909' AS cpfcgc UNION ALL SELECT '12345678000123' AS cpfcgc) AS X
```

Exemplo aplicado ao UPDATE informado:

```
UPDATE ger_ter
SET
    cpfcgc = IF(
        LENGTH(cpfcgc) = 14,
         CONCAT(SUBSTRING(cpfcgc, 1,2), '.', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,3,3), '.', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,6,3), '/', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,9,4), '-', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,13, 2)),
        CONCAT(SUBSTRING(cpfcgc, 1,3), '.', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,4,3), '.', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,7,3), '-', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,10,2))
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Seria assim:

```
CONCAT(SUBSTRING(cpfcgc, 1,3), '.', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,4,3), '.', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,7,3), '-', SUBSTRING(cpfcgc,10,2))
```

Veja aqui um exemplo funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c7c0/2

Comment: Perfeito...Era exatamente isto que estava com dificuldade.

Comment: Que bom, não esqueça de votar se a resposta foi útil

Comment: Claro...Muito obrigado novamente